# TransactionRequiredException when persisting inside a try/catch Exception block

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-7, jpa

I am not using Spring so that is no help, just plain Java EE 7 and I built a step monitoring interceptor for batch jobs which logs each step (successful or not) and persists the results in DB. Now for unsuccessful steps I catch the Exception and I call the logQueryOutcome method and it seems that when an Exception is thrown the Transaction is no longer available nor can I start a new one.

```
 public Object monitorStep(InvocationContext invocationContext) {
    try {
        //business logic here
        logQueryOutcome(invocationContext, result, timedDescription);
        return invocationContext.proceed();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logQueryOutcome(invocationContext, result, timedDescription);
        return null;
    }
}

private void logQueryOutcome(InvocationContext invocationContext, String result, String timedDescription) {
    stream(invocationContext.getParameters()).filter(s -> s instanceof String).forEach(s -> {
        String queryName = (String) s;
        monitoringRepository.logStepResult(queryName);
    });
}
```

And in the injected MonitoringRepository class the implementation for logStepResults is:

```
public void logStepResult(String queryName) {
    //Object instantiation and build
    Object obj = new Object(queryName)
    entityManager.persist(obj);
}
```

I simplified my code for the sake of the question.
My question is why does this transaction work fine for normal flow of batch job steps and fails to persist when an exception is thrown and is there a workaround for this?
I have tried adding Transactional with dontRollbackOn for Exceptions, I have tried TransactionAttribute such as REQUIRED or REQUIRES NEW in all methods but no luck. The project I am working on is also forcing me to use only annotation approaches so using Session or getting transactions from entity manager are not possible currently. This is the Exception:

```
Failed to run batchlet org.jberet.job.model.RefArtifact@32ba50d7: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: WFLYJPA0060: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.transactionIsRequired(AbstractEntityManager.java:877)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.persist(AbstractEntityManager.java:579)
    at com.myproj.MonitoringRepository.logStepResult(MonitoringRepository.java:28)
```